# else if condition ignored?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm fairly new to javascript and am trying to make something that allows people to access information about something that I like. E.g MLP or HoO, but my else if conditions seem to be ignored after the first else if.

```
var infoChoice = prompt("MLP, PJ&tO, or HoO?")
if (infoChoice != "MLP") {
    if (infoChoice != "PJ&tO") {
        if (infoChoice != "HoO") {
            confirm(infoChoice + " is not a valid option.")
        }
    }
} else if (infoChoice = "MLP") {
    confirm("MLP stands for My Little Pony. The 4th generation of MLP, known as MLP:FIM, (My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic) is by far the most well-known and beloved generation.")
} else if (infoChoice = "HoO") {
    confirm(infoChoice + " has been registered successfully.")
}
```

When I run it and search MLP it does fine, but any other "valid" option doesn't work. Please help, this is extremely frustrating.

Comment: `"=" != "=="`. Use the correct operator.

Comment: use == to compare values, single = sets a value

Answer (score 4):

The mistake is:

```
if (infoChoice = "MLP")
```

should be:

```
else if (infoChoice == "MLP")

else if (infoChoice == "HoO")
```

You are comparing values here, not assigning

Comment: Side note: Should be fixing whole `if` chain if you think this question deserves full answer.

Comment: @UncleIroh, for JavaScript is not too important

Comment: @AndreySapunov - You're right.  I just read the question where he states java and didn't see that he tagged it javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited set of possibilities, use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(prompt("MLP, PJ&tO, or HoO?").toLowerCase()) {
case "mlp":
    alert("MLP stands for My Little Pony. The 4th generation of MLP, known as MLP:FIM, (My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic) is by far the most well-known and beloved generation.");
    break;
case "hoo":
    alert(infoChoice + " has been registered successfully.");
    break;
case "pj&to":
    // do something?
    break;
default:
    alert("That is not a valid option.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My java is a bit rusty, but I think trying `else if (infoChoice.equals("MLP"))`
instead of using the `==` operator.  The reason is that `==` is a reference comparator, while .equals compares for value.

Check out this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov While it's tagged javascript the question clearly says "Java" so this is valid.

Comment: @UncleIroh Then perhaps the link should be thrown at the OP ;)

Comment: I didn't even realize the question was for javascript. My apologies.  The question does say "java" in the main body. In that case, Andrey's answer is correct. Use `==`

Comment: @nguyminh the question has been edited now to say javascript, the java/javascript mixups happen quite a lot in questions from people new to JS.